# jenkins error out on large file size

Tags: jenkins, web, jenkins-plugins, publishing

I am new to jenkins. I am trying to build a repo as a production on the server but when I click on 'build now' all files succeed except one large file with error as:

FTP: Caught exception [IOException caught while copying.] Sleeping for [10,000]ms before trying again

the file size is 137MB and it is an mp4 file.

I updated the plugins for both publish over ftp/ssh and still same problem.

help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is default time-out setting with SSH plugin. You can set it as long it takes to complete your task. Or simply set to 0 (zero) to avoid any timeout. With 0, it will basically keep the connection.